# Retrieve blood glucose data from BLE Glucose meter - Swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am trying to fetch the blood glucode data via CoreBluetooth from an Accucheck Instant glucometer and here is my method which is called from my didUpdateValueFor characteristic method -

```
private func glucoseValue(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Int {
  guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
  let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)

  let firstBitValue = byteArray[0] & 0x01
  if firstBitValue == 0 {
    // Glucose Value Format is in the 2nd byte
    return Int(byteArray[1])
  } else {
    // Glucose Value Format is in the 2nd and 3rd bytes
    return (Int(byteArray[1]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[2])
  }
}
```

I am however not getting the correct data and I'm getting an incorrect value.
Can you please help me out with what am I doing wrong and how do I format the data correctly to get the expected result?

Here is what gets printed in my console for the different UUIDs-

characteristic ==== <CBCharacteristic: 0x280034ea0, UUID = 2A18, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>

characteristic ==== <CBCharacteristic: 0x280034f00, UUID = 2A51, properties = 0x2, value = {length = 2, bytes = 0x2002}, notifying = NO>

characteristic ==== <CBCharacteristic: 0x280034f60, UUID = 2A52, properties = 0x28, value = {length = 4, bytes = 0x06000106}, notifying = NO>

characteristic ==== <CBCharacteristic: 0x280034fc0, UUID = 2A08, properties = 0x2, value = {length = 7, bytes = 0xe507031e0f3700}, notifying = NO>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the code you've written here. This doesn't look like the Glucose Measurement format. What format are you expecting that's encoded this way? You seem to be decoding several related characteristics that have different formats and represent different things. You probably want to start with the GLS docs (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/glucose-service-1-0/). You may also find the XML useful: https://github.com/oesmith/gatt-xml/blob/master/org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement_context.xml and this breakdown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813544/97337

Comment: Note that the Glucose Measurement characteristic is 0x2A18, which in your example above has no data in it (null).

Comment: You should use a BLE scanner app such as nRF Connect to see what characteristics your device has and what data they contain

Comment: The code you posted is the decoding for bluetooth heart rates

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I got nil for value of Glucose measurement characteristic value.

Comment: @AhmedShendy
Did you manage to solve it? I am also getting Characteristic value as nil for Glucose measurement. Can you help?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Yeah, I just forgot details about this, it is like a year now, give me sometime to revise the code, and remember which part was the solution.

Comment: @Sudhanshu I see the code now, but don't know how to help, feeling should revise to be able to explain and also leave a stackoverflow comment.

Comment: @Sudhanshu if you don't mind, can you remind me with which step/delegete-function does provide nil value?

Comment: @AhmedShendy didUpdateValueForCharacteristic in the peripheralDelegate is the method that provides the characteristic values. I am getting null for the glucose characteristics. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Sudhanshu I posted an answer, please check and be positive in rating. I would appreicate any feedback to improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since @Sudhanshu asked me how did I solve it, althought the question is a bit old, I thought to share my solution to help him/her/others out.

I couldn't have time to remember the details of my code, and I see now I should have written detailed comments on how I did it.

I have been talking with Bard since the past 3 hours, and couldn't help me explain enough my solution, but I got the following interesting points:

> - Using the correct characteristic for glucose data.
> - Implementing accurate SFLOAT parsing to extract the value correctly.
> - Validating parsed values against the glucometer readings.
> - Utilizing RCAP for synchronization to ensure the most recent data is captured.

I can confirm it related to RCAP but not remembering enough about it. So, guys you can mess with my code till you fully grasp it. I hope any of you can come back and edit my answer with code comments and more clear explaination.

```swift
extension AccuChekInstantReadingVC: CBPeripheralDelegate {

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        printDebug("didDiscoverServicesFor: \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown device name")")

        guard let services = peripheral.services else {
            if let error = error as? NSError {
                printError(error)
            }
            return
        }

        Task { @MainActor in
            // Search for the Glucose Service specifically
            if let service = services.first(where: { $0.uuid == GlucoseService_CBUUID }) {
                // Initiate discovery of necessary characteristics within the Glucose Service
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(
                    [
                        RecordAccessControlPoint_CBUUID,
                        MeasurementCharacteristic_CBUUID
                    ],
                    for: service
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        printDebug("didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor: \(String(describing: service.description))")

        // Ensure discovered characteristics are available
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
            return
        }

        printDebug("Found \(characteristics.count) characteristics.")

        Task { @MainActor in
            // Prioritize enabling notifications for the Measurement Characteristic
            if let characteristic = characteristics.first(
                where: { $0.uuid.isEqual(MeasurementCharacteristic_CBUUID) }
            ) {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        hideLoading()

        // Handle Measurement Characteristic updates
        if characteristic.service?.uuid == GlucoseService_CBUUID,
           characteristic.uuid == MeasurementCharacteristic_CBUUID {
            if let data = characteristic.value {
                let numberOfBytes = data.count
                var byteArray: [UInt8] = .init(repeating: 0, count: numberOfBytes)
                (data as NSData).getBytes(&byteArray, length: numberOfBytes)
                let floatValue: Float = [byteArray[12], byteArray[13]].extractSFloat()

                measurementValue = Int(round(floatValue * 100000))

                printDebug("Measurement Data: ", measurementValue ?? 0)

            } else {
                printDebug("Data: nil")
            }
        }

        // Handle RCAP Characteristic updates
        if characteristic.service?.uuid == GlucoseService_CBUUID,
           characteristic.uuid == RecordAccessControlPoint_CBUUID {
            if let data = characteristic.value {
                let numberOfBytes = data.count
                var byteArray: [UInt8] = .init(repeating: 0, count: numberOfBytes)
                (data as NSData).getBytes(&byteArray, length: numberOfBytes)

                if let measurementValue = measurementValue,
                   let lastBit = byteArray.last,
                   lastBit == 1 {
                    onReceivedReadingFromDevice(measurementValue)
                }

                printDebug("RCAP:", byteArray)

            } else {
                printDebug("RCAP: nil")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        printDebug("didUpdateNotificationStateFor: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        
        guard error == nil else {
            if let error = error as? NSError {
                printError(error)
            }
            
            return
        }
        
        Task { @MainActor in
            if characteristic.uuid == MeasurementCharacteristic_CBUUID,
               let characteristics = characteristic.service?.characteristics {
                if let characteristic = characteristics.first(
                    where: { $0.uuid.isEqual(RecordAccessControlPoint_CBUUID) }
                ) {
                    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1500_000_000)

                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                    
                    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 200_000_000)
                    
                    peripheral.writeValue(Data([0x01, 0x06]), for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would appreicate any feedback to improve the answer .

Comment: I would love to have it marked as the correct answer once approved by the poster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I just need a last help. I see we also need to set the Date and time to the BLE device. Were you able to do it? can you help in that?

Comment: @Sudhanshu You're welcome, kindly give a rate for my answer if found helpful.

Comment: @Sudhanshu For the other question, I never did it, but I can learn more by reading these documentations (They helped me before):
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/glucose-service-1-0-1/
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/glucose-profile-1-0-1/

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Upvoted your answer for quick responses and kind help. :)